# How to display a heatmap using dburles:google-maps Meteor package?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

**UPDATE:** Code  below is fixed as per accepted answer and is confirmed to be working.

I'm a bit stuck with Meteor, please help me out. 
I've installed the dburles:google-maps package and got the map to show markers just fine.
Then I tried to display a heatmap and it's causing an error, I can't resolve - "**Uncaught InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map(anonymous function)**"

Console output can be seen here - http://improveit.meteor.com/map

```js
Template.map.helpers({
  issueMapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('issueMap', function(issueMap) {
    

    var issueData = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.757676, -122.405118),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.757039, -122.404346),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.756335, -122.403719),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.755503, -122.403406),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.754665, -122.403242),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.753837, -122.403172),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.752986, -122.403112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
    ];       
      
      
      var issueArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(issueData);
      
       var heatMapLayer = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: issueArray,
            radius: 20
        });
      

      heatMapLayer.setMap(issueMap.instance);
      
      
  });
});
```

```html
 <template name="map">
  <h1>Issue heat map</h1>
  <p>This map will display issues and their severity</p>
   <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="issueMap" options=issueMapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
heatMapLayer.setMap(issueMap);
```

to

```
heatMapLayer.setMap(issueMap.instance);
```

The setMap method requires a google map instance. the callback of `.ready` does not directly provide this as it also has an `options` object for extra convenience.

I confirmed it works on your site:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Akshat for your time! I thought about this, but I didn't try it for some reason.

Comment: @PvUtrix Its not immediately clear. It's the first time i've seen that library. I had to toy around a bit to find where this place was they burn garbage!

Answer (score 0):

```js
Template.map.helpers({
  issueMapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('issueMap', function(issueMap) {
    

    var issueData = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.757676, -122.405118),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.757039, -122.404346),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.756335, -122.403719),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.755503, -122.403406),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.754665, -122.403242),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.753837, -122.403172),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.752986, -122.403112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
    ];       
      
      
      var issueArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(issueData);
      
       var heatMapLayer = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: issueArray,
            radius: 20
        });
      

      heatMapLayer.setMap(issueMap.instance);
      
      
  });
});
```

```html
 <template name="map">
  <h1>Issue heat map</h1>
  <p>This map will display issues and their severity</p>
   <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="issueMap" options=issueMapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: please, provide not just code, but also some valuable information. what was wrong? how did you fix it?