# How do I add the Google Maps Visualization Library when using the dburles:google-maps Meteor package?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I wish to use Google Map's Visualization library to make [a heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer). However, I'm using the dburles:google-maps Meteor package, and am unsure how I should include the Google Maps API. The Google Maps documentation suggest this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false">
</script>
```

How do I do this in Meteor? I know that this should be possible, because someone was able to do this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637517/how-to-display-a-heatmap-using-dburlesgoogle-maps-meteor-package).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, super simple fix. The dburles:google-maps package actually takes care of this!

```
GoogleMaps.load({
      key: myKey,
      libraries: 'places,visualization'
    });
```

as opposed to just loading the places library:

```
libraries: 'places'
```